# Configuration Manager Client does not install properly

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I am trying to get our sccm clients installed properly on our machines. It was working a few weeks ago but recently noticed that clients have not been installing properly. The CCM client is installed on the machines but only two evaluation cycle actions are present and we get errors in our ccm.log (posted below). I turned off both the server firewall and the client firewall but it made no difference.

Below is a shot of what happens in the log when we push the ccm client to a machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log that you provided does not show any errors. There are red lines due to some keywords in the lines, but overall, what I saw there was ok.
Most likely you have issues with clients registering with your SCCM Server. For these issues check the following logs: ClientIDManagerStartup.log on the affected clients side and MP_RegistrationManager.log on the ManagementPoint side.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I am going to investigate today.

Comment: Getting: "[RegTask] - Server rejected registration request: 3 ClientIDManagerStartup 3/8/2017 4:26:08 PM 2312 (0x0908)" inside the ClientIDManagerStartup.log.  Now lets see the MP_RegistrationManager.log.

Comment: Several clients are reporting a bad certificate in MP_RegistrationManager.log. I think we found our issue. Ill post an update when we investigate the certificate.